# ffmpeg how to make moving text smooth?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command for creating scrolling text from a text file:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=25:fontcolor=black:x=30:y=h-n*5:textfile='credits.txt'[out]" -c:v libx264 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 scrolling.mp4
```

This will slowly move the text found in `credits.txt` upwards, but does so discretely every second, rather then smoothly over time. The section that controls this is the `y=h-n*5`, where `n` is the frame number I believe, which I thought would be updated every frame, but appears it behaves exactly the same as if I were to replace it with `t`.

If anyone knows of any way of smoothly moving text using ffmepg, or any other method at all such as image magick, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The text should be moved up by 5 pixels each frame - can you post a sample of what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered it was because upon the creation of the video `vid.mp4`, I had the frame rate set to 1. That way there was only 1 fps, hence the "discrete movement every second".

Upon creation of the initial file I included `-r 1` in the options, setting this to `-r 30` created the desired effect of smooth movement.

Comment: If you used `ffmpeg` to create `vid.mp4` then you can create it and use drawtext in one command and have fewer steps and less generational quality loss.

Comment: Would I do that just by including `-vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=25:fontcolor=black:x=30:y=h-n*5:textfile='credits.txt'[out]"`?

Comment: Maybe. I'd have to see the command you used to create `vid.mp4`.